# integral identity relating to tan(x)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can I prove the integral identity below?

> $$
> \int_0^{\pi/12}\ln \Big(\cot x \tan^2(3x)\Big)dx=\int_0^{\pi/12}\ln \Big(\tan x\Big(\frac{3-\tan^2x}{1-3\tan^2x}\Big)^2\Big)dx=0
> $$

where we employed the fact that $\tan(3x)=\tan x\frac{3-\tan^2x}{1-3\tan^2x}$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the identity:
$$\int_0^a f(x)dx=\int_0^a f(a-x)dx$$
And then try to add them.
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/12}\ln(\cot x)+2\int_0^{\pi/12}\ln(\tan 3x)\\=\int_0^{\pi/12}\ln(\cot x)+2\int_0^{\pi/12}\ln(\tan (3(\pi/12-x)))\\=\int_0^{\pi/12}\ln(\cot x)+2\int_0^{\pi/12}\ln(\tan (\pi/4-3x))$$

Comment: Tks. But I don't think this method is the best one after some attempts. $\tan(\pi/12)=\tan(\pi/3-\pi/4)=2-\sqrt{3}$ just makes a cockamamie integrand. So can you provide me with another one?

Comment: @Roger209 first try $x\mapsto 6x,dx\mapsto6dx,\{0,\pi/12\}\mapsto\{0,\pi/2\}$

Comment: I will try it again.(Besides, I have edited my origional question above.)